# How to remove docker image entry (but not the image) with <none> tag which has multiple non-none tag entries

Tags: docker

I have a number of docker images with multiple tags.

Say there are 3 entries (as shown by docker image ls | fgrep image) with the same ID:

- image:tag1
- image:tag2
- image:<none>

How do i remove the 'image3:<none>' entry but keep the other 2 entries?

you can't
'docker image rm image3:<none>' or
'docker image rm image3:'
and i don't want to do 'docker image rm ID'

I've looked at a number of stackoverflow entries but none seem to cover this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1. Tag the image ID to any arbitrary tag *with the same image name*. For example, if your image is called `my_image:<none>` and has image ID `0a279023f465`, execute `docker tag 0a279023f465 my_image:delete_me`.
2. Review the list of docker images and see that `my_image:<none>` has been replaced by `my_image:delete_me`.
3. You can now delete the tag, e.g. `docker image rm my_image:delete_me`.
4. Review the list of docker images and see that both `my_image:<none>` and `my_image:delete_me` are gone, but other tags remain intact.

Comment: i would not have expected this behavior from docker image tag.I will try this next time i need to cleanup my docker registry.